# TouchableOpacity doesn't respond

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm very new to React native and lately just been messing around with it. I've been having problems every time I use one of the touchable components. For some reason it doesn't respond when I click the touchable component. I tried looking at other solutions but got no where. (I'm also using Expo if you need to know that)

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const StartScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require("../assets/Background.png")}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.ContentArea}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={console.log("Button pressed!")}>
          <View style={styles.nextButton}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 }}>Test</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ContentArea: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  nextButton: {
    width: 150,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
    marginBottom: 45,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
});

export default StartScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a function invocation inside the `onPress` method. This makes the console.log run on the render. `console.log()` returns undefined, so your `onPress` prop is ultimately `undefined` itself. What you want to do, is pass a reference to a function, or an anonymous function instead. Here's an example:

```
...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Button pressed!")}>
  <View style={styles.nextButton}>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 }}>Test</Text>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>

...
```